# Store data to a file in encrypted form in c# windows 10 universal app development

Tags: c#, file, security, encryption, windows-10

Here I tried to write some text into a file locally in encrypted form.But when i see the file locally the data is not in encrypted form.
Can someone please correct me.

```
    //Writing to file
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    // textBlock.Text = folder.Path;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(
                "Text input into sample.txt file", Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sampleFile, buffer);

    //Reading from file
    StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
    string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
    // textBlock.Text = text;
```

Comment: Utf8 is not encryption and `ConvertStringToBinary` is not method to perform encryption. Not sure if your sample is related to your question...

Comment: I am new to app development , I tried this by following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx , Canyou please some tutorials to encrypt data in a file and decrypt it again.

Comment: Please tell us how you plan to secure your encryption keys first...

Comment: I need to store a string locally in encrypt form and decrypt it while retrieving the string in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CryptographicEngine` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.aspx) to actually perform encryption and decryption.

But to [@Neil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223478/neil-mcguigan) comment above - *where do you store the decryption key*? If the key is stored as part of the app, it isn't really protecting anything. If it is derived from user input (eg, a password they enter every time + an optional salt) that's better.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using Windows.Security.Credentials? Or is storing user credentials inside the credentials locker bad practice?

Comment: Storing credentials in the locker is great. The question was "where do they come from in the first place"

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation could be used if you want to keep secrets in code. However this might also be broken but at least it will make it a little more difficult to break the security and hence less incentive to try and hack it. In the end the amount of protection needed depends on the importance of data you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt or decrypt storagefile UWP

```
 public static async Task<StorageFile> EncryptStorageFileLocalUserAsync(this StorageFile FileForEncryption)
    {
        //"LOCAL = user"
        IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(FileForEncryption);
        IBuffer SecuredData = await DataProtectionStream("LOCAL = user", data);
        var  EncryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(
          "EncryptedFile" + FileForEncryption.FileType, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(EncryptedFile, SecuredData);
        return EncryptedFile;
       // Reporting.DisplayMessage( "File encryption successfull. File stored at " + EncryptedFile.Path + "\n\n");

    }
    public static async Task<StorageFile> DecryptStorageFileLocalUserAsync(this StorageFile EncryptedFile)
    {

        IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(EncryptedFile);
        IBuffer UnSecuredData = await DataUnprotectStream(data);

         var DecryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(
          "DecryptedFile" + EncryptedFile.FileType, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(DecryptedFile, UnSecuredData);
       // Reporting.DisplayMessage("File decryption successfull. File stored at " + DecryptedFile.Path + "\n\n");
        return DecryptedFile;

    }
```